# Finding a design matrix

Tags: regression, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to understand how a design matrix was obtained in this problem below.

Consider the one sample problem:

$Y_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2), 1 \le i \le n$. with the $Y_i's$ i.i.d. The MLE is:

$\hat\mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i$.

Find a design matrix $X$ such that $\hat\mu = (X^{T} X)^{-1} X^{T} Y$.

The answer is $X = 1_n$.

I am not sure how to achieve this answer. I was thinking of viewing this as a regression problem, where $Y = X\mu + \epsilon$ and defining.

- $Y = ( \begin{matrix} Y_1 \\\ ... \\\ Y_n \end{matrix} )$
- $ \mu = ( \begin{matrix} \mu_1 \\\ ... \\\ \mu_n \end{matrix} )$, and $Y \mu^{-1} = X$ and solving for X this what but I am not sure I can do this as $Y$ and $\mu$ are column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I guess I was fixated on $X$ having to be an $n$ by $n$ matrix but did not consider that $n$ could equal $1$. So, I pretty much broke down what the OLS estimates should equal to in matrix terms.

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i}{n} = \frac{1}{n}* (1,...,1) * (\begin{matrix} Y_1 \\\ ... \\\ Y_n \end{matrix})
$$

Thus, setting $X = ( 1_n)$ gives us one possible solution to this question.

Comment: Your formula for $X$ makes no sense, because it stacks a $1$-vector $1_1$ over a $2$-vector over ... over an $n$-vector $1_n.$  The model simply is $Y=\mathbf 1_n \mu + \varepsilon$ where $\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon)=\sigma^2,$ showing $X=\mathbf 1_n.$

Comment: I added some edits to your LaTeX in both the question and the answer, but I'm not sure about your notation with the parentheses. If these are supposed to represent vectors, I would make sure you edit that into both parts here, and clarify that you have a full answer rather than "I think I have the answer", which may not be helpful to others if you have not actually solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I will edit this to make it better. @ShawnHemelstrand